# How to lookup an item by multiple indexes in matlab

Tags: matlab, search, matrix-indexing

I have a n+1 column matrix.
I want a function mySearch(idx1,idx2...,idxn) that returns the n+1'th column in the row whose first n elements are equal to idx1...idxn

Next step, i want mySearch to return a value which is closest to the indexes, by some simple interpolation.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `norm` to determine the distance and `min` to get the closest value:

```
function v=mySearch( idx, M )
n=length(idx);
d=[]
for row = M'
   d=[d; norm(row(1:n)-idx) ]
end 
[~, I]=min(d);
v = M(I,n+1);
end function
```

Above `idx` is a vector of `[idx1, idx2, ..., idxn]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use function `find` - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Example

```
[rol,col]=find(matrix(idx1==SOMETHING))
```

This gives you the positions in the matrix of the points you want. This way, you can also find positions close to their position, depending on your criteria